Strike-through text paragraph containing equations
I have several paragraphs of text that contain equation environments and in-line equations.  How do I cross out/strike through these paragraphs using ulem package?  I tried the suggestions in this post but there are still issues with math mode.
My MWE is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  % cross out unwanted text
\newcommand\soutpars[1]{\let\helpcmd\sout\parhelp#1\par\relax\relax}
\long\def\parhelp#1\par#2\relax{%
  \helpcmd{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else\par\parhelp#2\relax\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\soutpars{\lipsum[1]  

\begin{equation} 
z^2=x^2+y^2 
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]  $r=\sin\theta$  \lipsum[3]}

\soutpars{\blindmathpaper}

\end{document}


Use lua-ul instead (requires compilation with lualatex):
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}

\strikeThrough{\lipsum[1]  

\begin{equation} 
z^2=x^2+y^2 
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]  $r=\sin\theta$  \lipsum[3]}

\strikeThrough{\blindmathpaper}

\end{document}


thanks, but is it possible to use a package that compiles with pdfLaTex?

@MedullaOblongata For highlighting etc. lual-ul is really the most robust choice. If you use such features, this packages makes it worth switching to lualatex
